# How to select only users, who have exactly two actions

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have a table with a columns: customer_id, event_name and event_date. I want to select only users who has login event, scroll event or login + scroll events.

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE events (
  customer_id INT,
  event_name VARCHAR(20),
  event_date DATE
);

INSERT INTO events (customer_id, event_name, event_date)
VALUES
  (1, 'click', '2023-04-17'),
  (2, 'login', '2023-04-17'),
  (3, 'scroll', '2023-04-18'),
  (4, 'login', '2023-04-16'),
  (5, 'click', '2023-04-15'),
  (1, 'scroll', '2023-04-14'),
  (2, 'click', '2023-04-13'),
  (3, 'login', '2023-04-12');
```

I have tried this:

```
SELECT customer_id
from events
GROUP BY customer_id
having SUM(CASE WHEN event_name in ('login', 'scroll') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
and SUM(CASE WHEN event_name not in ('login','scroll') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

But this does not work and return only those who did only one of those actions, but I want to return users who have: scroll, login or both.

It should return users 3 and 4.

Comment: What should be returned for your example? It seems like first and last paragraphs are contradictory.

Comment: But id does return 3 and 4, it is ok. see here https://dbfiddle.uk/c98EW-dL

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS` for this:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT customer_id
from events t
WHERE EXISTS (
        select 1
        from events t1
        where t.customer_id = t1.customer_id
        and t1.event_name in ('login', 'scroll')
    )
AND NOT EXISTS (
        select 1
        from events t1
        where t.customer_id = t1.customer_id
        and t1.event_name not in ('login', 'scroll')
    );
```

Demo (in MySQL) can be seen [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/siGU9KJG).